# How can I find the most repeated word in a list, with at least one difference

Tags: python

How can I find the most repeated word in a list, with at least one difference??

Lets say I have a list with words:

`my_list= ['dog', 'cat', 'bat', 'cow', 'sheep', 'bot', 'dug', 'sheop', 'bag', 'cut', 'dat']`

So my expected output would be:

```
out
['cat', 'bat', 'bot', 'bag', 'dat']
```

I know there is a simple way to do this, but I don't know how.

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Why is `'sheep'` not in the output?

Comment: So, think of this as building a graph where each word (node) is linked to every word which is only one character different - then he wants the node of highest degree (most edges) along with all its neighbors.

Comment: Why not `cat` in your output list?

Comment: Are you asking for an algorithm/process or for the actual code?

Comment: Are you just comparing just the letters in the string or letters in the same sequence? Is ```tob``` *one different* from ```bat```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you excluded cat from your output, perhaps racism against cats! Jokes aside, this function does exactly what you asked for, but it also includes cat in it's returned list. I think you forgot to include cat in your output, if not so, please provide us with more details so we can help:

```
def wordsOfOneDiff(main_str, seq):
    "Find words in seq that differ from man_str by only one character"

    diff = 0
    res = []

    for name in my_list:
        for c in main_str:
            if c not in name:
                diff += 1
        if diff <= 1:
            res.append(name)
        diff = 0
    return res
```

This function simply counts the number of the different characters and if the different characters are less than or equal to one, the function appends `name` in `res`.

Basically, if `diff` is less than 1 this means `diff` is 0. When `diff` is zero this means there's no different character in `name` compared to `main_str` and hence `name` == `main_str`. Add `print(diff)` at the outer loop to see how this works, pretty much simplified.

---

Output:

```
 >>> wordsOfOneDiff('bat', my_list))
 ['cat', 'bat', 'bot', 'bag', 'dat']
```

Comment: Hey! Yeah, sorry, I forgot to include cat. This was almost what I needed, but I also forgot to point that the order of the letters is important.
It took me a while but I finally got it using your code as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of numpy and a function to compare two strings (from SequenceMatcher), you can compute the distance between each tuple of words.
Then you keep the one that matches the best all the other words. Finally you get back the similar words using your pre-compute similarities:

```
import numpy
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

my_list= ['dog', 'cat', 'bat', 'cow', 'sheep', 'bot', 'dug', 'sheop', 'bag', 'cut', 'dat']

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

s = [0] * len(my_list)
m = numpy.zeros((len(my_list),len(my_list)))
for i, e in enumerate(my_list):
    for j, f in enumerate(my_list):
         if not e == f:
            m[i,j] = similar(e,f)
            s[i] += m[i,j]

s = numpy.array(s)
best = numpy.asarray(my_list)[s == numpy.max(s)]
l_b = list([best])
for b in best:
    tp = numpy.array(m[my_list.index(b)])
    l_b.append(numpy.asarray(my_list)[tp == numpy.max(tp)].tolist())
print set([x for y in l_b for x in y])
# set(['dat', 'bag', 'bat', 'bot', 'cat'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want:

```
l = ['hello','hallo','holla','helio','cat','cap','tap','dog','hallo','hello']

def most_common(lst):
    return max(set(lst), key=lst.count)


def match(s1, s2):
    ok = False
    for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2):
        if c1 != c2:
            if ok:
                return False
            else:
                ok = True
    return ok


def best(lst):
  results=[]
  for n  in range(len(lst)):
    results.append(0)
    for i in range (len(lst)):
      if match(str(lst[n]),str(lst[i])):
        results[n] += 1
  index = results.index(max(results))
  return lst[index]

print (best(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools, operator
# added 'cot' to the list to create a tie
# added 'tab' to the list for testing a different form of the rule
test = ['dog', 'cat', 'bat', 'cow', 'sheep', 'bot', 'dug',
        'sheop', 'bag', 'cut', 'dat', 'cot', 'tab']
test.sort()
```

Define your rule for filtering your data:

```
def only_one_different(a, b):
    '''Counts the letters in a and b and returns True if there is only one different'''
    a = collections.Counter(a)
    b = collections.Counter(b)
    # c and d are needed in case len(a) != len(b)
    c = a - b
    d = b - a
    return sum(c.values()) == 1 or sum(d.values()) == 1

def only_one_different(a, b):
    '''Compare a and b in sequence and return True if only one is different'''
    count = sum(c != d for c,d in itertools.zip_longest(a, b))
    return count == 1

# a couple of helpers
first = operator.itemgetter(0)
second = operator.itemgetter(1)
def count(item):
    return len(second(item))
```

Find all the possible *edges* and filter for your criteria: a *filtered* edge would be `('bag', 'bat')`.

```
possibles = itertools.permutations(test, 2)
edges = ((a,b) for a, b in possibles if only_one_different(a, b))
```

Group the edges by the first word in each edge and determine most number of repeats.  An example of a *grouped edge* is `('bot', [('bot', 'bat'), ('bot', 'cot')])`

```
repeated = [(k, list(g)) for k, g in itertools.groupby(edges, first)]
most = max(count(thing) for thing in repeated)
```

In case there are ties, filter for the most edges

```
most_repeats = (group for group in repeated if count(group) == most)
```

Finally, gather up each word and its repeats

```
for word, group in most_repeats:
    g = [word]
    _, repeats = zip(*group)
    g.extend(repeats)
    print(g)
```

Result:

```
['bat', 'bag', 'bot', 'cat', 'dat']
['cat', 'bat', 'cot', 'cut', 'dat']
['cot', 'bot', 'cat', 'cow', 'cut']
```